# Leaflet layer spy

Tags: leaflet

OpenLayers3 has a really neat [layer-spy example](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.2.1/examples/layer-spy.html). The [source code](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.2.1/examples/layer-spy.js) for the example indicates it uses the `precompose` and `postcompose` event listeners for an `ol.layer.Tile`:

```
var imagery = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.BingMaps({key: key, imagerySet: 'Aerial'})
});

// before rendering the layer, do some clipping
imagery.on('precompose', function(event) {
  var ctx = event.context;
  var pixelRatio = event.frameState.pixelRatio;
  ctx.save();
  ctx.beginPath();
  if (mousePosition) {
    // only show a circle around the mouse
    ctx.arc(mousePosition[0] * pixelRatio, mousePosition[1] * pixelRatio,
        radius * pixelRatio, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.lineWidth = 5 * pixelRatio;
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)';
    ctx.stroke();
  }
  ctx.clip();
});

// after rendering the layer, restore the canvas context
imagery.on('postcompose', function(event) {
  var ctx = event.context;
  ctx.restore();
});
```

[image]

---

However I'd like to use Leaflet to implement the same functionality. **Is there a Leaflet implementation of the layer spy functionality? If not, which event listeners are useful for implementing it with a Leaflet `TileLayer`?**

Comment: Although the accepted answer is great, I'd still be interested in an implementation that doesn't sit on top of the "spy" (markers, and especially popups).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for the exact same functionality (but not in the precompose / postcompose), you would probably be interested in [leaflet-tilelayer-mask plugin](https://github.com/frogcat/leaflet-tilelayer-mask) ([demo](https://frogcat.github.io/leaflet-tilelayer-mask/default/)).

> Leaflet-tilelayer-mask adds mask effect to tilelayer.

[image: leaflet-tilelayer-mask screenshot]

Comment: Brilliant, thanks so much. Need to up my google-fu...